# Onepage after choose guest checkout magento redirect to cart

Tags: magento

I have strange problem .
In checkout onepage i can't checkout as Guest or via registration,only via login method.
When I choose checkout as guest or registration and click submit magento redirects to cart. 
I tried copy templates on fresh copy of magento  but to not avail.
maybe someone knows how to fix this problem??
Thanks!

Comment: Did you do any customization to onepage checkout or using any custom module that may affect it? Did you check to see if you have any JS errors or your server error logs?

Comment: i checked onepage in console of Firebag and onsubmit guest checkout or with registeration i received 500 internal server error. i'll try to check it via logs. thank U

Answer (score 0):

Enable loggin system and check the log files.
Maybe you have some code error (like wrong function name or result) and this cause the redirect.
Did you made some customization?